# Vim insert-mode completion ends on typing backslash

Tags: php, vim, backslash, tab-completion

I have a problem with vim's tag completion feature for php namespaces.
Every time I type backslash, vim's completion popup goes away (even with `iskeyword+=\\`).

Let's say we have next class in our project:

```
Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle
```

After every backslash I have to type "C-x C-]" to get my completion popup back on the screen. That's very annoying and really pisses me off.

Could someone explain why this happens and maybe suggest some workaround?

Comment: :help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-]

Comment: @glts, it's tag-based completion. See `:help ins-completion`.

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't do *automatic* completion: the completion shortcut has to be typed again and again if you want multiple consecutive completions. You can see the principle at play when doing filename completion.

You should try one of the few autocompletion plugins available: neocomplete, autocomplpop, ycm...